# Higher order recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have the following non-homogenous recurrence relation and I'm trying to solve it using characteristics roots method :

$a_n = 10a_{n-1} -37a_{n-2} + 60a_{n-3} -36a_{n-4} +4$ for $n \ge4$ and $
a_3 = a_2 = a_1 = a_0 = 1$

I found the particular solution p =1 and I'm trying to solve the homogenous equation when $a_n = r^n$ but it will be an equation of the fourth order !!My question is whether this is the right path or there's any shortcut to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

We have $$(a_n+1)-10(a_{n-1}+1)+37(a_{n-2}+1)-60(a_{n-3}+1)+36(a_{n-4}+1)=0$$

Set $a_n+1=b_n$ and use [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving)

Comment: Why you added 1 to each an?

Comment: @Lisa, to balance out $4=1-10+37-60+36$

Comment: But how will you solve the fourth ordered equation?

Comment: @Lisa, fortunately, the roots are $$3,3,2,2$$

Comment: How could you know?

Answer (score 0):

Use generating functions. Define $A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n$, write the recurrence without subtractions in indices:
$$
a_{n + 4} = 10 a_{n + 3} - 37 a_{n + 2} + 60 a_{n + 1} - 36 a_n + 4
$$
Multiply by $z^n$, sum over $n \ge 0$ and recognize sums like:
$$
\sum_{n \ge 0} a_{n + k} z^n
  = \frac{A(z) - a_0 - a_1 z - \ldots - a_{k - 1} z^{k - 1}}{z^k}
$$
to get:
$$
\frac{A(z) - 1 - z - z^2 - z^3}{z^4}
  = 10 \frac{A(z) - 1 - z - z^2}{z^3}
      - 37 \frac{A(z) - 1 - z}{z^2}
      + 60 \frac{A(z) - 1}{z}
      - 36 A(z) + 4 \frac{1}{1 - z}
$$
Surprisingly it turns out that:
$$
A(z) = \frac{1}{1 - z}
$$
so that
$$
a_n = 1
$$

[maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net) did the heavy lifting.